# Inductive limits of test function spaces and local convexity

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, locally-convex-spaces

This question is motivated by the test function spaces for distributions, but to be simple just let $K_i=[-i,i]\subseteq\mathbb R$, $i=1,2,\ldots$, and consider the inductive limit topology of the continuous functions $C_i$ on $\mathbb R$ with supports subsets of $K_i$, with the $\sup$ norm. Within the context of distribution theory, the usual definition for the topology of the continuous functions with compact support is the finest locally convex topology such that the inclusions are continuous, but here we take the straight inductive limit, dropping the locally convex condition.

For a monotone decreasing sequence $t$ of positive numbers $t_i$, define the set $U_t$ to be the continuous functions of compact support with supremum on $K_i$ smaller than $t_i$. It is easily seen that the sets $U_t$ are convex. Claim: the collection of $U_t$ is an neighborhood base at $0$ in the inductive limit topology. $U_t\cap C_i$ is the ball of functions in $C_i$ with supremum smaller than $t_i$, and so $U_t$ is open in the inductive limit topology. Suppose $U\ni 0$ is open. Then $U\cap C_i$ contains a ball about $0$, say of radius $t_i$. Inductively, one can choose $t_i$ decreasing. Let $f\in U_t$ have compact support $K$, and choose $i$ so large that $K\subseteq[-i,i]$. Then $f$ has supremum smaller than $t_i$ and support within $K_i$, so $f\in U$, because that ball is contained in $U$. 
Thus the straight inductive limit topology is already locally convex in this case.

The topologies used for distributional test function spaces take steps (convex hulls) to manually ensure the relevant inductive limit topologies are locally convex. They must have to do that. But the above seems to indicate that those spaces are locally convex apriori. No need for the convex hulls. What's wrong here?

*Added in edit*: The above argument also shows that the inductive limit of
normed spaces is locally convex. But the spaces $D_{K_i}$ are not normed. The
analogous statement for that case has for a monotone sequence $t=\{t_i\}$ and an
increasing sequence $n=\{n_i\}$, the sets $U_{t,n}$, with derivatives
up to an including $n_i$ bounded in absolute value by $t_i$ on $K_i$, are a
base for the inductive limit topology. These sorts of sets are inherently
nonconvex, because a convex sum of two functions may increase the support of
either, and so, given membership in $U$, such a convex sum may increase the control on higher
derivatives around $0$, but simultaneously may not comply and decrease such
derivatives accordingly.

For example, take a function $f$ with support in $[1/4,3/4]$ with maximum $1$
but high first derivative. This can be in $U_{t,n}$ with $t_1=1$ and
$n_1=0$. Add to this a function $g$ with support in $[5/4,7/4]$ which has value
and first derivative less than $1/2$ in absolute value. This can be in
$U_{t,n}$ with $t_2=1/2$ and $n_2=1$. But $(f+g)/2$ may not be in such a
$U_{t,n}$ because the support of that is not within $[-1,1]$ and support
exceeding $[-1,1]$ has first derivative smaller than $1/2$, which need not be
the case for $(f+g)/2$.

The answer to the question posed is: nothing is wrong, but the argument
extended does not lead to a *convex* local base at $0$ for the inductive limit
topology on the space of distributional test functions.

Such explicit local bases seem helpful for understanding. For example, even in
the continuous case in the question originally posed, one can easily form a net on the sequences $t$, by
translating a bump function $f_0$ with support in, say, $[1/4,3/4]$ by $i$ and
multiplying by $t_i$. That is, $f_t(x)=t_i f_0(x-i)$ if $x\in K_i$. Such a net
does not have support in any $K_i$ but it does converge to the zero
function.

The argument in https://mathoverflow.net/a/333618/59219 seems to show that
if $U$ is a convex open set in the inductive limit topology and
$U_{t,n}\subseteq U$ then the sequence $n$ is eventually constant. This would
seem to imply that the $U_{t,n}$ with $n$ a constant sequence, is a local base at $0$ for the test function
topology, which would in my opinion clarify that topology, by providing an easy to understand local base at $0$.

Comment: You know the tempered distributions ? That's what happens when changing the test function space topology. And from the topology perspective, the convolution operator is probably the most important to look at.

Comment: Yes, but I want to understand the more primitive ordinary test function spaces.

Comment: I think your argument is correct (and quite interesting to me). I was thinking about the same thing, but really for the usual spaces of test functions. In this case, it is not true that the usual inductive limit topology is already locally convex; see my just-posted answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/333618/59219

Comment: Thanks for the link, which I studied in detail. The arugument there shows that the union of the $U_k$ defined as the
$C^\infty$ functions with support in $[-k,k]$ and derivative up to an including
$k$ smaller that $1/k$, has no convex open neighbourhood of $0$ in the inductive limit topology. This is a
slightly more geometric stance.